# EOF error requiring file when compiling

Tags: crystal-lang

So I currently have the current directory structure:

```
- project
  - lib
    - struct
      - external
        - external.cr
  - src
    - project
      - version.cr
    - project.cr
  - ...
  - shard.yml
```

I am currently compiling my code using the current command, whilst in the main project directory (containing shard.yml):

```
`crystal src/project.cr`

I then receive the following error:

Error in src/project.cr:2: while requiring "struct/external"

require "struct/external"
^

Syntax error in lib/struct/external/external.cr:15: expecting identifier 'end', not 'EOF'
```

My project.cr file looks like this:

```
require "./project/*"
require "struct/external"

# Doc omitted 
module Project
    extend self
end
```

My external.cr file looks like this:

```
#
class External
    def initialize(@vertices : Array(SubclassOne), @edges : Array(SubclassTwo))
end

#
class SubclassOne
    def initialize()
end

#
class SubclassTwo
    def initialize()
end
```

Comment: Method definitions should have `end` at the end: `def initialize(); end`

Answer (score 0):

The functions within the classes in the external file were missing the `end` keyword.